# SQL Concatenate - ignore null values - result should have no spaces

Tags: sql, concatenation

I am looking to concatenate four columns into a computed column. Any of the four columns could have null values. The resulting computed column should have no spaces - just the combination of the four fields.

I have tried about a dozen options including coalesce, IFNULL etc. Below is a sample of some of the code I have tried.

```
(CONCAT([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]))

CONCAT((ISNULL, Column1, ''), (ISNULL, Column2, ''), (ISNULL, Column3, ''), (ISNULL, Column4, ''))

ISNULL(Column1, '') + ISNULL(Column2, '') + ISNULL(Column3, '')+ ISNULL(Column4, '')

CONCAT(((isnull([Column1],''), isnull([Column2],'')), isnull([Column3],'')), isnull([Column4],''))

CONCAT(COALESCE (Column1, N'') , COALESCE (Column2, N'') , COALESCE (Column3, N'') , COALESCE (Column4, N''))
```

Here is a sample of data and my desired outcome:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column2 | Column2 | RESULTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 5 | B | c | XYZ5Bc |
| UGH | 9 |  | a | UGH9a |
|  | 8 | G | c | 8Gc |
| IJH |  | K | b | IJHKb |
| KUJ | 6 | Y |  | KUJ6Y |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your last version should work if the empty values are `NULL`.  Perhaps you also need to explain what the empty values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays, many databases support the very convenient `concat_ws()` function.  With that, you would simply use:

```
select concat_ws('', column1, column2, column3, column4)
```

If the values have spaces at the beginning or end, you can use `trim()`:

```
select concat_ws('', trim(column1), trim(column2), trim(column3), trim(column4))
```

If your database does not support `concat_ws()` there are work-arounds.  However, the specific work-around depends on the database you are using.